# Admin LTE Submenus not remaining open on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, adminlte

I have incorporated AdminLTE template for my Visual Basic Project. I want the same effect which has been used for the demo:
https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index.html , i.e when you click on sub menu in the Tree view drop down the targeted page open but the Tree view stays open and shows which page is active. Which is not happening in my case, when I click on the sub menu, it takes me to the targeted page, but the Tree view closes automatically.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

On the menus, the active class set according to the route and you need to put active conditions manually according to each route.